# Compression library with the ability to extract specific items

Tags: .net, windows, compression

I have a Windows Desktop application with the following setup:

**(1)** As the application is running a number of long strings will be generated: string1, string2, string3, ...

**(2)** The strings will be similar, e.g. string8 will be string7 plus a small change.

**(3)** A user of the application may wish to view any of the strings that have been generated. So the user might view string3, then string1, then string9.

I would like to use a **compression library** to reduce the space needed to store all these strings. In particular I would like a compression library that:

**(1)** Can add each new string to an existing "archive" (just in-memory storage)

**(2)** Dynamically adjusts the compression dictionary (e.g. LZ77), to take advantage of the 
fact that each new string is similar to the previous string.

**(3)** Allows me to extract specific strings that have already been added to the "archive". So for example, if the archive contains strings 1-10,000, I would like to be able to extract string314 without having to decompress the whole "archive". This is mainly for speed, and to avoid having the entire decompressed archive in memory at any one time.

I would have thought that GIT would do something similar for file revisions, though I'm not sure of this. I believe that GIT uses zlib, but when looking at the zlib documentation it didn't look like the above workflow was supported.

**NOTE:** I realise I could store the diffs of the strings instead. However I would prefer to store the entire strings for safety.

Comment: The compression works by "re-using" similar components (that varies by the exact algorithm) so I'd expect that this directly violates your requirement of directly accessing `n`-th element without processing any other elements

Comment: I wouldn't expect that adding the `n+1`th element changes the representation of the `n`th element. An exception might be if we reinitialize the compression dictionary and recompress the `n`th element.

I don't have any experience with compression algorithms though, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding git: I get the impression that from using git that compression is used while transferring data over the network. I don't think it stores diffs compressed. But this is just a guess based on empirical observation while using the program.

Here's a possible solution for you based on [Huffman codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding):

- Scan through all of your strings and build a character frequency table.
- Use the frequency table to encode each string more efficiently.
- Stuff each string into a file and track the offset to each string.
- Create a separate index that contains the offset to each string. This index will can also hold the character frequency table.

The program that needs to use these strings will read the character frequency table and build a Huffman tree/table based on that. Then, if it needs string314, it looks up offset #314 in the table, jumps to the point in the concatenated compressed string file, and starts decompressing that string.